# Hide standard field and copy data in the new recreated custom field

Tags: custom-field, data, page-layout, hidden-fields

I have a standard field called currency but I need to change its data type from picklist to multi-select picklist.

The problem is that it is not possible to change the data type of standard fields in Salesforce.

Therefore I'm trying to  recreate the standard currency field but instead of removing the standard currency field is it possible to hide it in the layout?

What I would like to achieve is to hide the standard currency field and copy its data into the new field.

Could you please advise how this can be achieved?

Could you please advise how to copy the data from the standard currency field into the new recreated field.

Regards,

Dilyan

Comment: You can hide from pagelayout.. On detail page of object click on `Edit Layout` link.. And for copying the data. If you just wanted to copy the data then use formula field. If you can't use formula field then use workflow rule for field upadate

Answer (score 1):

What you can try here is create new field and display it on UI. Now remove the old currency field.

Now use Batch(for large number of records) or Developer console and copy data from your old field to new field. And in future use this new field reference everywhere.

**Note**: Please check your code and WF and formula fields an update the reference accordingly.